# $\mathcal{P}(\omega) \cap L \subseteq L_{\omega_1}$

Tags: logic, set-theory

I read in a question on here, that $\mathcal{P}(\omega) \cap L \subseteq L_{\omega_1}$. With replacement, $\mathcal{P}(\omega) \cap L$ has to be definable after some $\gamma$ because for all $x \in L$ there has to be a smallest $\alpha$ such that $ x \in L_\alpha$.

But why can't $\gamma > \omega_1$? I assume that if $\gamma<\omega_1$ is no problem because since L is transitive,  $\mathcal{P}(\omega) \cap L$ would still be a subset of $L_{\omega_1}$, although I suspect there is a different reason for that.

Comment: For the second part, since $|\alpha|=|L_\alpha|$ and Cantors theorem holds in $L$, the power set has to be $\geq |\omega_1|$. Not sure tho...

Answer (score 1):

This - and more generally the fact that $L\models\mathsf{GCH}$ - is a consequence of **condensation**.

Suppose $r$ is a real in $L_\gamma$. Let $M$ be a countable elementary submodel of $L_\gamma$ with $r\in M$ (this exists by downward Lowenheim-Skolem); by condensation, the Mostowski collapse of $M$ is $L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ which is countable since $M$ is, and the Mostowski collapse map doesn't move reals so $r\in L_\alpha$.

(For higher cardinals we argue as follows. If $s\subseteq \kappa$ and $s\in L_\theta$ we form an elementary submodel $M$ of $L_\theta$ with $s\in M$, $\kappa\subseteq M$, and $\vert M\vert=\kappa$. The condition $\kappa\subseteq M$ ensures that the Mostowski collapse of $M$ doesn't affect $s$. This shows that for every cardinal $\kappa$, every constructible subset of $\kappa$ is in $L_{\kappa^+}$, and in fact in $L_{\kappa^{+L}}$ since the argument "internalizes" to $L$ itself.)